# Kurento WebRTC not recording unless both audio and video streams are present

Tags: webrtc, audio-recording, video-recording, kurento

Basically subj. I am using Kurento-Utils for JS. That topic has been discussed for the case of lower-level work, but at this point in project, it is too late to go switch approach :(

When i stream webcam with audio it is recorded nicely into a .webm file. But, how do i stream audio only, or video only? An attempt results in file being of 0 size with no error messages.

Is there any sample code for Kurento-utils/js which would demonstrate that use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the appropriate `MediaType` when instantiating the recorder, and connecting the elements.

```
pipeline.create('RecorderEndpoint', {uri: filepath,mediaProfile:'WEBM_AUDIO_ONLY'}, 
            function (error, recorder) {
                webrtcEp.connect(recorder,'AUDIO', function (err) {
                    recorder.record();
                    console.log("recording started ...");
                });
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I think that structure also contains a lot of other interesting stuff, just not documented well enough :), is there a FULL list of possible options it accepts, except uri and mediaProfile?

Comment: @MikhailNovikov Hey! Hold your horses :-P It's all in the [JSDoc](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/langdoc/jsdoc/kurento-client-js/module-elements.RecorderEndpoint.html). I see that there is some text missing, so perhaps we have an issue with the JSDoc generation. In that case, you can also check the [JavaDoc](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_static/langdoc/javadoc/org/kurento/client/RecorderEndpoint.html). There is no extra info apart from the `MediaProfileSpecType` and the URL.